# Are there any ePaper modules that are bigger than 2.7 inches for arduino

Tags: arduino-mega, display, components

I am looking for a large ePaper Display for the Arduino. The issue is is that I cannot seem to find one any larger than 4.5 inches in size. That will be compatible with arduino. Even with a controller board.

Are there any companies that sell controller boards for these displays? Is there anyone who can manufacture these epd displays upon request?

I am looking to take this project to a pcb board after I prototype it so do I need to build my own controller? If what parts would you need? Is it easy for a designer with intermediate capability?

I can find all kinds of display like at [pervasivedisplays.com](http://www.pervasivedisplays.com/) and [Mouser.com](http://mouser.com)

The end goal is to create a Arduino based project that I can score skeet with to keep track of my average score.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to start the other way: find a sw stack that is known to work and check if any of the controllers/displays it already supports fits your needs. This is how I would do it.

[Here](http://ugfx.org/platforms) is a starting point.